# How to use ajax call to populate line graph in highcharts

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

I am trying to draw a simple line graph with highcharts in asp.net.  I'm cannot get anything drawn though.  Here is what I've got so far:

```
var chart;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({  
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'  
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Rank vs. Time'
            },    
            xAxis: {
                numerical: [],
                title: {
                    text: 'Year'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Rank'
                }
            },

        });
        getData();
    });

function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/Name/GetBoyNamesByYear?name=matthew",
            success: function (data) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: "Matthew",
                    data: data
                });
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

My ajax returns something in the format of

```
 [{"$id":"1","Year":1995,"Rank":2},{"$id":"2","Year":1996,"Rank":2},{"$id":"3","Year":1981,"Rank":3},{"$id":"4","Year":1982,"Rank":3}, .......
```

And if it matters in my html I have:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

edit:  Solved the issue.
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a.Year > b.Year ? 1 : -1;
                    });

```
                data = $.map(data, function (i) {
                    return { x: i['Year'], y: i['Rank'] };
                });

                chart.addSeries({
                    name: "Matthew",
                    data: data,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius: 1
                    },
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems.

1.) Highcharts has no idea what to plot with your arbitrary series properties. What corresponds to the X and Y values?  It is very specific about [how the data needs to be formatted](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data).  I'm assuming you want `Year` as the X and `Rank` as the Y.

2.) Your data is not sorted by the X value.

Combining these two problems:

```
var data = [{"$id":"1","Year":1995,"Rank":2},{"$id":"2","Year":1996,"Rank":2},{"$id":"3","Year":1981,"Rank":3},{"$id":"4","Year":1982,"Rank":3}];

data.sort(function(a,b){return a['Year'] > b['Year']});

data = $.map(data, function(i){
    return {x: i['Year'],y: i['Rank']};
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2A5VD/).

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I will try it.  My question is then is this going to be slower than the edit that I made above? Right now its taking a lot of time for the chart to generate, like ~8 seconds by doing it the way above that I'm adding all the individual points.

Comment: Found the error to be in the sorting of the data.  Edited code above to show working version